# Is it possible to deploy multiple ArcGIS Server Instances from one Virtual Machine?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, virtual-machine

I would like to deploy between 4 and 5 ArcGIS Server 10.2.1 instances with different licenses on one machine.  Can this be accomplished by pointing the server to different ports via the web adaptor or another method?  I would also have other 3rd party applications on this physical machine with 1-3 virtual machines.  The ideal configuration would be a RAID with 32 Gigs of RAM on one physical machine.

Comment: Not really. If you did seriously unsafe things to the underlying components on a Linux box, you'd come closest, but this is not a sustainable deployment option. Besides, running 5 instances in only 32Gb of RAM is suboptimal (should be 16-24Gb each). Finally,10.2.2 has been out a *while* -- that should be your target (with its dozen-plus patches).

Comment: We are sticking at 10.2.1 because there are 3rd party applications that are not compatible with 10.2.2 or later versions.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  Might help provide an answer that differs to what you want, but is a good deployment?